# OpenXml.Spreadsheet class throws FileFormatException error on simple excel file

Tags: c#, openxml

I need to read 50MB .XLS excel but im getting this error:

```
System.IO.FileFormatException {"File contains corrupted data."}
```

I choose OpenXMLReader class for reading, because it seems to fit on this scenario.
But it crash on the first line of code.

```
SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false)
```

The Excel file can be downloaded here:
http://www.filedropper.com/saxfile its simple 97-2003 excel test file with 10 rows

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadExcelFileSAX(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\SAXFile.xls");
        }

    static void ReadExcelFileSAX(string filename)
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

            OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
            string text;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
                {
                    text = reader.GetText();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 4):

The file you're trying to open is a pre-OpenXML binary format Excel file.

I'm sure the reader raises an error as soon as it detects it is not a valid ZIP archive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i do not understand it. I want to read excel files, so how can i to do that ?

Comment: For .XLSX the Code works, so maybe if it possible to change format .xls to .xlsx programmatically ? That could be an another way.

Answer (score 0):

This code before using OpenXML will help (it save xls as xlsx), but its little bit workaround

```
    static void ConvertXlsToXlsx(string xlsFilePath, string xlsxFilePath)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook eWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsFilePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        eWorkbook.SaveAs(xlsxFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        eWorkbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
```

Better solution is maybe to use different library ExcelDataReader
https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/
which i tested and work (example print .CSV to Console)

```
    static void XLSFileStreamReader(string filePath)
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        // Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
        IExcelDataReader excelReader2003 = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

        // DataSet - The result of each spreadsheet will be created in the result.Tables
        DataSet result = excelReader2003.AsDataSet();

        // Data Reader methods
        foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                    Console.Write("\"" + table.Rows[i].ItemArray[j] + "\";");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        // Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
        excelReader2003.Close();
    }
```

i found it here https://gist.github.com/Munawwar/924413

PS: FileStream maybe should be in USING block.

Answer (score 0):

Use ExcelDataReader for xls and xlsx.

```
public static DataTable XLSFileStreamReader(string filePath)
{

    try
    {

        FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        //IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

        IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;
        excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);

        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

        excelReader.Close();

        return result.Tables[0];

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        
        throw;
    }

}
```